# How to figure out why thread is stuck?

Tags: java, debugging, jodatime, stack-trace, jstack

I see this thread in my jstack that does not appear to be moving at all. Any pointers on how to figure out why it's stuck? I don't see any locks or anything, the only suspicious thing is the "Object.wait()" reference.

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3a8000b000 nid=0x942 in Object.wait() [0x00007f3a89539000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.<clinit>(DateTimeZone.java:95)
        at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.withZoneUTC(DateTimeFormatter.java:301)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer.<clinit>(AWS4Signer.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.SignerFactory.createSigner(SignerFactory.java:121)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.SignerFactory.lookupAndCreateSigner(SignerFactory.java:107)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.SignerFactory.getSigner(SignerFactory.java:80)
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.computeSignerByServiceRegion(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:311)
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.computeSignerByURI(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:284)
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.setEndpoint(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:160)
```

Also, line 95 in DateTimeZone.java at the top of the stack is this:

```
   public static final DateTimeZone UTC = new FixedDateTimeZone("UTC", "UTC", 0, 0);
```

There is another thread that's also stuck in a similar place:

```
"FeatureManagerService" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3a8056a800 nid=0x94f in Object.wait() [0x00007f3a84151000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at com.amazonaws.util.DateUtils.<clinit>(DateUtils.java:35)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.<clinit>(ServiceUtils.java:59)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3Signer.sign(S3Signer.java:123)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:348)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:245)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3711)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3664)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:620)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:603)
```

And DateUtils.java:35 is:

```
private static final DateTimeZone GMT = new FixedDateTimeZone("GMT", "GMT", 0, 0);
```

I already tried looking into it with jvisualvm/jhat but didn't really get very far.

Note that this is a live process, not something I am running in my debugger locally and after restart it works fine so it appears to be intermittent.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

*Update* using the mixed mode in jstack seems to give some more insight - it's waiting on a pthread_cond_wait:

```
----------------- 2370 -----------------
0x00007f3a89115414      __pthread_cond_wait + 0xc4
0x00007f3a8833a03c      _ZN13ObjectMonitor4waitElbP6Thread + 0x7dc
0x00007f3a88117fbb      _ZN13instanceKlass15initialize_implE19instanceKlassHandleP6Thread + 0x36b
0x00007f3a881182ca      _ZN13instanceKlass10initializeEP6Thread + 0x6a
0x00007f3a8814d3f3      _ZN18InterpreterRuntime4_newEP10JavaThreadP19constantPoolOopDesci + 0x143
0x00007f3a7d01d9ee      * org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.<clinit>() bci:0 line:95 (Interpreted frame)
0x00007f3a7d0004f7      <StubRoutines>
...
```

Comment: Got any other threads doing things? Got a thread dump?

Comment: There are a few other threads - what should I be looking for?

Comment: @ssnobody found another thread stuck before creating a FixedDateTimeZone

Comment: I believe most hangs in java are due to either infinite loops or waits on locks. Investigating synchronized methods or blocks that would obtain these locks would be my first pass, but it may also be useful to simply obtain a listing of these. That listing should be found in the LK subcomponent dump routine of a thread dump / javacore. In addition, javadump (the tool that generates the thread dump) can sometimes diagnose the deadlock itself straight away.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @ssnobody I don't see any locks or synchronizations between those two threads, should be thread-safe. The one thing that looks odd is that they are both stuck before initializing a static object of the same time, but I don't see any locks. How do I look at the LK subcomponent?

Comment: See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142/html/usejavadump.html?path=0_5_1#usejavadump and http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142/html/deadlockdetect.html?path=0_5_1_3_1#deadlockdetect

Comment: I tried that but I don't get the LK information - it looks like that might be something specific to IBM JVM whereas i am using HotSpot JVM.

Comment: Could this be a bug? See "Deadlock in DateTimeZone/FixedDateTimeZone static initialization" at https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/171 (hope you weren't the one that actually reported it as it is quite recent)

Comment: @ChristopheAugier yep, that's exactly what it is!

Comment: @ChristopheAugier, the nice people from AWS helped raise the issue you just found with Joda after helping me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not stuck. It's just calling new DateTimeZone() in a loop, and the constructor does some computations. Every time you look at this thread, it's inside DateTimeZone() - but it's a different DateTimeZone() each time.

Which then gets discarded. Happened to me quite a few times.

Comment: You're totally right that that's what sometimes happens but you can usually tell by the address of the variable and in this case the address stays the same which makes me think it's not a loop. Good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

As found by @naumcho, this proved to be a bug (https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/171).

Based on the information provided (stack traces of two different threads + source line) one could have suspected a deadlock because both threads are trying to instantiate a new object of the same type `FixedDateTimeZone`.

The next step to confirm that would be to use GDB to inspect the stack frames around `__pthread_cond_wait()`.